# File icons blurry when loaded with an icon handler shell extension

Tags: winapi, shell-extensions

I have a shell extension with an icon handler that sets a file type's icons to a green or red icon, based on file contents. The icons seem to work properly except they are really blurry when using large icons, as if they were zoomed in from a really small size. The icon `.ico` files contain all image sizes from 256x256 to 16x16.

[image: Icons are blurry]

I am using a very basic icon handler, but maybe there could still be some problem with caching or something. How could I make sure the icons are loaded properly?

```
HRESULT icon_handler::GetIconLocation(UINT u_flags, PWSTR psz_icon_file, UINT cch_max, int* pi_index, UINT* pw_flags)
{
    *pw_flags = GIL_NOTFILENAME | GIL_DONTCACHE;
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT icon_handler::Extract(PCWSTR psz_file, UINT n_icon_index, HICON* phicon_large, HICON* phicon_small, UINT n_icon_size)
{
    int icon = ICON_GREEN;
    if (m_icon_color_ == 1) {
        icon = ICON_RED;
    }

    if (phicon_large != nullptr)
    {
        const int large_size = LOWORD(n_icon_size);
        *phicon_large = HICON(LoadImageW(global_h_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(icon), IMAGE_ICON, large_size, large_size, 
            LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
    }
    if (phicon_small != nullptr)
    {
        const int small_size = HIWORD(n_icon_size);
        *phicon_small = HICON(LoadImageW(global_h_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(icon), IMAGE_ICON, small_size, small_size,
            LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

When logging with DebugView the icon handler appears to request appropriate sizes:

```
[30100] phicon_large size:
[30100] 256
[30100] phicon_small size:
[30100] 16
```

**Edit**:
As per @Anders, if I check the size of the image loaded with `LoadImage` it also appears to be correct:

```
*phicon_large = HICON(LoadImageW(global_h_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(icon), IMAGE_ICON, large_size, large_size, 
            LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
ICONINFOEXW info = {sizeof(ICONINFOEXW)};
GetIconInfoEx(*phicon_large, &info)
BITMAP bmp;
GetObjectW(info.hbmMask, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
OutputDebugStringW(L"Icon size:");
OutputDebugStringW(std::to_wstring(bmp.bmWidth).c_str());
```

```
[12376] phicon_large size:
[12376] 256
[12376] Icon size:
[12376] 256
[12376] phicon_small size:
[12376] 16
[12376] Icon size:
[12376] 16
```

Comment: Inspect the icon you get from `LoadImage` with `GetIconInfoEx` to see if it actually is the correct size.

Comment: Thank you, I checked this and the size of the loaded image also seems to be correct.

Comment: Not sure this applies here, but worth a look: [How do I override the default icon selection algorithm?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121005-00/?p=6393)

Comment: Next thing to try: Add something to the 16x16 icon to make sure it is not that icon it is using as the large icon. And if that does not help, try using a single icon image size per resource (HICONs can contain secret info that links back to the file it is loaded from).

Comment: What are the flags passed in initially to GetIconLocation (u_flags)?

Comment: @SimonMourier u_flags is `GIL_CHECKSHIELD (0x0200)`. Don't know what it means but I guess I'll add `GIL_FORCENOSHIELD` into `pw_flags`, heh.

Comment: I am now getting sharp icons most of the time (https://i.imgur.com/u9X6DqD.png) after trying out different tools to create the .ico files. Not sure how much of it is Windows' icon cache so I'm trying to refresh with `nirsoft shellrefresh` and Explorer restart. 

I'll look into @Anders' single 256px icon for `phicon_large` or Strive Sun's custom Extract function if I cannot figure this out.

Comment: @Mr.RanDum hi, Mr.Ran You can take a look at my latest updated answers, which may be helpful to you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this kind of information from past [documents](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiots-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Exten-9).I can't guarantee that this information is accurate now.

> nIconSize
>
> Indicates the desired sizes of the icons. The high word is
>   the dimensions (both height and width, since they're always the same)
>   of the small icon, and the low word holds the dimensions of the of the
>   large icon. Under normal circumstances, the small icon size will be
>   16. The large icon will usually be 32 or 48, depending on which view mode Explorer is in - 32 for large icon mode, 48 for tile mode.

It seems that `IExtract IconA:: Extract` can only extract icons in standard sizes.

On the other hand, refer Raymond Chen's [old thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=1103),

> if you ask IExtract­Icon::Extract to extract an icon at a particular
>   size, the function can return S_FALSE.The Extract­Icon and
>   Extract­Icon­Ex functions don’t let you
>   specify a custom size,
>   and Load­Image doesn’t work with icon indices
>   (only resource IDs).

**Therefore,If you need to extract icons of custom sizes (i.e., something other than the system's "small" and "large" sizes)**, then you'll need to do more work.

Call the [SHGetImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetimagelist) function, which is another shell helper function, but one that retrieves a shell image list containing icons. It gives you far more options for icon sizes: `SHIL_SMALL` (generally 16x16), `SHIL_LARGE` (generally 32x32), `SHIL_EXTRALARGE` (generally 48x48), and `SHIL_JUMBO` (generally 256x256—only on Vista and later). So if you ask for `SHIL_EXTRALARGE`, you'll get the 48x48 icons that you're looking for.

You'll still need the [SHGetFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) function here, but this time it will be to retrieve the index of the desired icon in the shell image list. Retrieve that with the `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` option.

Completely untested sample code, never touched by a compiler:

```
HICON ExtractExtraLargeIcon(LPCTSTR pszPath)
{    
    // Determine the index of the desired icon
    // in the system image list.
    SHGETFILEINFO sfi;
    SHGetFileInfo(pszPath, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);

    // Retrieve the system image list.
    // (To get 256x256 icons, we use `SHIL_JUMBO`.)
    IImageList* piml;
    if (SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO, IID_IImageList, (void**)&piml) == S_OK)
    {
        HICON hIcon;
        if (piml->GetIcon(sfi.iIcon, ILD_TRANSPARENT, &hIcon) == S_OK)
        {
           return hIcon;
        }
    }

    // Oops! We failed.
    return NULL;
}
```

More Details, please refer :

[Difference between ExtractIcon and ExtractAssociatedIcon? Need to extract icon of specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370241/difference-between-extracticon-and-extractassociatedicon-need-to-extract-icon-o/37419253#37419253)

[Extract high resolution icon or thumbnail for file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839588/extract-high-resolution-icon-or-thumbnail-for-file)

**Updated:**

I accidentally found such a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241174/how-do-you-draw-an-icon-inside-a-window-in-c-winapi), probably by specifying the width/height, remove `LR_DEFAULTSIZE`. Also, you must call `DestroyIcon` after `DrawIconEx` otherwise you get resource leak. Either that or create the `HICON` on heap so that it's created only once.

Comment: I think SHGetFileInfo just calls IExtractIcon and related interfaces.